# Spotify preview app List view getItem

Tags: spotify

I'm using the v1.0 preview of Spotify's Apps API. When trying to create a custom List by supplying the opt_options parameter of List.forPlaylist(list, opt_options), I get errors regarding DOM elements not found. This is almost certainly due to my naive implementation.

My question is does anyone have an example of how to use this opt_options with a custom getItem function? The documentation isn't clear on what I am meant to return or populate.

My implementation (in which playlist is a loaded list):

```
listView.forPlaylist(playlist, { getItem : function (item, index) {
            console.log(item);
            console.log(index);
            return $("<span>hello, world</span>");
        }
    }
```

This errors every time:

```
DOMException code: 8 message: "NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8" name:
"NOT_FOUND_ERR" stack: "Error: An attempt was made to reference a Node
in a context where it does not exist.?    at f.createItems
($views/scripts/list/view.js:16:147)?    at e.b
($views/scripts/list.js:16:102)?    at e.Observable.dispatchEvent
($api/scripts/models.js:4:322)?    at Promise.f.snapshot
($views/scripts/list/model.js:9:244)?    at Promise.done
($api/scripts/models.js:6:157)?    at f.snapshot
($views/scripts/list/model.js:7:241)?    at e.more
($views/scripts/list.js:4:138)?    at f.moreWithLimit
($views/scripts/list/model.js:17:127)?    at f.checkResizeEdge
($views/scripts/list/view.js:13:457)?    at f.init.b
($views/scripts/list/view.js:3:3)"
```

Any thoughts welcome. An example, even more so ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a DOM element, not a jQuery object. For that, you need to return

```
$("<span>hello, world</span>")[0];
```

instead of returning

```
$("<span>hello, world</span>");
```

You have more information about the difference between them on [jQuery object and DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element).

Here you have a complete example of how you would inject a [List view](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/views/views-list-list.html) in your Spotify app:

```js
require([
  '$api/models',
  '$views/list#List'
], function (models, List) {
  'use strict';

  var playlist = models.Playlist.fromURI('spotify:user:nowplaylist:playlist:6QHyDeqaPNZ0nyLFJbSKTL');
  var listView = List.forPlaylist(playlist, {
    getItem : function (item, index) {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(index);
        return $("<span>hello, world</span>")[0];
    }
  });

  document.body.appendChild(listView.node);
  listView.init();
});
```

Comment: That's great thanks @JMPerez - any idea if there's anything similar to the 0.x Track View that used to make this so easy? :-) It seems totally missing.

Comment: @AndyBareWeb In 1.0 there is no Track View afaik. What do you want a Track look like, that you need a custom renderer?

Comment: I want to render a button as an additional column - with 0.x API I did the following

return new views.List(playlist, function(track) {
                var trackEx = new views.Track(track,
                                    views.Track.FIELD.NAME |
                                    views.Track.FIELD.STAR |
                                    views.Track.FIELD.ARTIST |
                                    views.Track.FIELD.DURATION);

                $(trackEx.node).append("my custom button");
                return trackEx;
                                            });

Comment: So far there is no way to achieve that. The `getItem` method that exists today is just for very customized content, where you provide the full content for one row, so it wouldn't be enough here.