# Why does $(elem).data() work but jQuery.data() not work?

Tags: jquery, data-binding

This is really weird to me. Why does `$("element").data(.....);` work but not `jQuery.data(....);`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Rdh2e/6/

According to the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

you should be able to use `jQuery.data` to attach data to elements as well....

Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) expects the first argument to be a dom element reference not a jQuery wrapper object

> element: The DOM element to associate with the data.

```
jQuery.data($("#kit")[0], "says", "meow");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BhRYJ/)

when you pass `$("#kit")` it is passing a jQuery wrapper object, not a dom element reference, you can access the first element in the jQuery wrapper by using the index `0` or like `$("#kit").get(0)`

Comment: Ah.... I see. Thank you. May I quickly ask what is the difference between a jQuery wrapper object and a DOM element reference?

Comment: @Gnuey see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element