# getElementsByTagName Equivalent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I need some help in converting a javascrpipt function into jQuery. Below is my original JS code:

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
```

After a little research on Stack I was able to come up with this equivalent:

```
var text = $(data).$('pre')[0].html();
```

Where data is the data I receive in a `$.get` request, like below.

```
$.get (
    mypage,
    function parse(data) {
        var raw = $(data).$('pre')[0].html();
    }
);
```

But that doesn't seem to work and i'm not very good with jQuery.

Comment: Did you try $('pre').html()

Comment: [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Comment: @Manish, that doesnt work with the `get` request. It just gives me the data for the page i'm on and not for the page I requested

Comment: btw if your original js code works, leave it as it is: it will perform faster than jQuery, and it already looks clear enough ^^

Comment: @moonwave99, i'm using this to get around using something like an iFrame

Answer (score 1):

Granted that `data` holds HTML, `$(data).find('pre').eq(0).html()` should do.

Comment: But then when I do `alert(raw)`, it just returns as `null`

Comment: @user3151541 please provide a sample of your `data` response then.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first element with tag `pre` from data you can do the following in jQuery,

```
$('pre',data).eq(0).html();
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: context? u using jQuery v1.4.2?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea sry do you mean some kind of reference? just updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason `$(data).$('pre')[0].html();` doesn't work is that the `[0]` part extracts the first found element as a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so invoking `.html()` fails.

Others have already pointed out the solution.  `.eq(0)` gets the first element as a jQuery object (per moonwave99 and melc's answers), and that's why you can then call `.html()` on it.

For further reading on the difference, see: [jQuery object and DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)