# How do you turn jQuery's $('#foo') into an object as created by document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that takes the return value of document.createElement and puts it in a popup on the screen. However, I want this object to be passed to the popup to be an already created div so that I can manipulate the popup content easily.

Basically, I want to turn this:

```
var magicDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Into:

```
var magicDiv = $('#divToBeTurnedIntoElement').html();
```

In the first case, document.createElement has a specific return object. I am looking for the jQuery function that returns the same kind of object as document.createElement.
In both cases, magicDiv should be the exact same object, but with the jQuery version, it is created based on an existing div. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you looking for `$('#divToBeTurnedIntoElement')[0]` or [`.get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)?

Comment: `var magicDiv = $("<div>");` is equivalent

Comment: Do you want `var magicDiv = $($('#divToBeTurnedIntoElement').prop('outerHTML'));` or the clearner way `var magicDiv = $('#divToBeTurnedIntoElement').clone();`

Comment: Are you trying to create a new div as a copy of the existing one on the page, or grab a JQuery object referring to the existing div on the page?

Comment: very closely related: [jQuery object and DOM element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element) (although that question seems to assume some familiarity with DOM objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [*DOM object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). DOM objects are often returned by DOM selection and creation methods, like `document.createElement` and `document.getElementById`.

A jQuery object contains a list (or, really, *is* a list) of DOM objects. jQuery saves you the trouble of interacting directly with DOM objects (which have an inconsistently-implemented API across browsers) by exposing a standardized API on the `jQuery` object.

In order to extract a low-level DOM object out of a `jQuery` instance, you can use [`.get(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the n<sup>th</sup> DOM element from the jQuery object's list of DOM elements:

```
var magicDiv = $('#divToBeTurnedIntoElement').get(0);
```

You can also use normal array indexing,`$('#divToBeTurnedIntoElement')[0]`, which is a bit shorter but slightly less flexible (e.g., it doesn't support negative indexing).

Comment: Thanks, this answer came closest. I used $('#divToBeTurnedIntoElement'.find("#innerDiv"))[0]. This worked great!