# Parent of DOM element that is returned by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a problem understanding what is wrong here. I use jQuery to find an element, but I fail finding the element's parent without using jQuery:

```
$(".selectbox").on("click", function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;
   find_parent(eTarget);
});
```

using above to call find_parent function works:

```
function find_parent (el) {
   element_parent = el.parentElement;
}
```

but if use this to call find_parent it fails:

```
function someFunction {
   selectBoxEl = $(".xyz").find('.selectbox');
   find_parent (selectBoxEl);
}
```

I am not looking for the solution of "why not using jQuery parent()" - and it works fine. I am trying to **understand** why normal DOM methods don't work on an element returned by jQuery and what I am doing wrong.

***Edit:***
Sample code above is not the actual code being used, but a very simplified version to illustrate my question. The actual `find_parent()` function is a long and complicated piece that goes through many elements and their parents for various updates and it doesn't use jQuery. I want to leverage that code and not duplicating it for my need in the sample function `someFunction()`.

Comment: you have typo... there should not be space in between methodcall and round braces `find_parent(selectBoxEl);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery object and DOM element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, the event object is already normalized, there is no need to have browser specific code in it. so `$(".selectbox").on("click", function (e) {
    var parent = $(e.target).parent();
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny—or far more efficient: `e.target.parentNode`. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element returned by jQuery is wrapped. Use `find_parent(selectBoxEl[0]);`

Comment: You mean the Object returned by *.find* is not a DOM element, it's a jQuery instance and doesn't have a *parentElement* property (though I daresay there will be a *parentElement* method one day that returns another jQuery object with a single member that is the parentNode of the first element in the matched collection, or no members at all).

Answer (score 1):

As already you are using jQuery, there is no need use separate function to identify parent DOM element. `$('#id').parent()` returns parent DOM element.

Still if you want to use .parentElement javascript method, use below method.

```
$('#id')[0].parentElement
```

JQuery is not actually returning any DOM element, it will return only instance of DOM object. parentElement propery has to be apply only for DOM element not for instance object.