# Changing the text color of the text box back to black

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with dynamic text boxes and fetches data from the backend. When user clicks on the text-box, the color of the text in the text box changes and when the form is submitted, a confirmation message is displayed and with it, I want the text boxes color to be changed back to black. I have tried changing the color, but it is not happening. 
Here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {'postData':JSON.stringify(postData)},
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Rows updated successfully';
            $("#contentsID").text(successmessage);
            var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
            var textBoxes = $("input[type = 'text']");
            textBoxes.attr("disabled", checkboxes.is(":checked"));
            $('#varEdit').prop('checked', false);
            $('#saveEdits').prop('disabled', true);
            textBoxes.text.style.color ='#000000';
            //textBoxes.style.color = '#000000';

        },
```

can someone take a dig on it.

Comment: understand difference between `Jquery object and dom ` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('input[type="text"]').css('color','#000');
```

instead of

```
textBoxes.text.style.color ='#000000';
```

Answer (score 1):

`textBoxes` hold jquery obj, then use :

```
textBoxes.css('color','#000');
```

Otherwise use :

```
textBoxes[0].style.color ='#000';
```

Comment: i would assume that textBoxes contains multiple, so would want to loop them rather than just change the first occurrence (this comment is only directed at the second solution).