# How to find document events

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-events

I'm doing this to listen for `pause` event in Cordova:

`$(document).on('pause', function( e ) { ... });`

and now I need to check whether the `pause` event is attached to `$(document)`.

I have tried to do: `$._data($(document), 'events')` and `$.data($(document), 'events')` but they always return `undefined`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass DOM object and not jquery object, work like this :

```
$._data(document, 'events')
$.data(document, 'events')
```

Or with jquery object like :

```
$(document).data("events");
```

Take a look at **[jQuery object and DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```