# Animating width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Hello everyone,

```
    $(".textF").animate({width: actualWidth + "px"}, durations[0]*1000);
```

Fast question. This works because I got it with jQuery. But I have a lot of spans with that class and if I do it this way doesn't work:

```
    var fElements=document.getElementsByClassName("textF");
    fElements[0].animate({width: actualWidth + "px"}, durations[0]*1000);
```

The error I get:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.

Comment: You included `jQuery` in your page, why you used `pure JS`?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean you included `jQuery`, so why you tired to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `$('...')`?

Comment: Because it didn't create my "var fElements" as an Array. Using getElementsByClassName did

Comment: you didn't get me bro, but its okay ;)

Comment: I think I got you. I mean, i tried to get all my span elements into an array using `var fElements=$("textF");`, but trying to print its length said undefined. That's why I used javascript. Anyway, thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jquery` not working with native `javaScript` function .

**Error?-**
`animate()` is defined by jquery not with native `Javascript`

Refer the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) jquery documentation

```
$(fElements[0]).animate({width: actualWidth + "px"}, durations[0]*1000);
```

or

```
$(fElements).eq(0).animate({width: actualWidth + "px"}, durations[0]*1000);
```

Comment: There is no need to use `px` in `animate` function. the default unit is pixel.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciated. What's the difference though? I don't really get it. I know it's about DOM elements but...

Comment: @DavidPradellCasellas  because jquery declaration is different from native js declaration .Better see this thread for more clarity about that [difference between dom and jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @DavidPradellCasellas always welcome..Keep learning ..Happy coding..:-)