# cannot set property 'color' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a custom error message and styling based on validation (I know about plugins, but the time involved in coordinating the validation plugin with Materialize is too much for a single field).

HTML:

```
<div class="input-field inline center-align">
  <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" class="">
  <label for="qty" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" 
       class="active">Qty</label>
  <span id="qty-error">really?</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#quantity').change(function(){
  var $Qty = $(this).val();
  var $Label = $('#qty-error');
  if ($Qty > 0 && $Qty <= $AvailTix){
      $Label.html('seems reasonable');
      $Label.style.color = '#8e8ef5';
      $(this).addClass('valid');
  } else if ($Qty < 1){
      $Label.html('really?');
      $Label.style.color ='#f96d63';
      $(this).addClass('invalid');
  }
});
```

What's confusing me is that the `$Label.html` piece is working. It changes the text. But I get this error in the console for the `$Label.style.color` line:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.style` is property of an element. With jQuery you've that element in array. More like [elem]. So, use:

```
$Label.css('color', '#f96d63');
```

or

```
$Label.get(0).style.color = '#8e8ef5';
```

But the first one is more *jQueryish*.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to access a DOM property `style`on a jQuery object, that's why you got `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`.

In your code `$Label` is a jQuery object and don't have a `style` property because `.style` is a DOM object property so you can't use it with a jQuery object.

You need to use **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method instead:

```
$Label.css('color', '#8e8ef5');
```

For more details you can read **[jQuery object and DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)**.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when you failed to bind style to an element appropriately. In AngularJS for instance `<div *ngStyle="styleClass(variable)">{{variable.time}}</div>` this will return cannot set undefined property color. Instead you should do this `<div {ngStyle}="styleClass(variable)>{{variable.time}}</div>`

for details on binding in AngularJS https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/

Answer (score 0):

`$Label` is a jQuery object, not a standard node element, so you can either do `$Label[0].style.color = '#8e8ef5';` or `$Label.css('color', '#8e8ef5');`

Answer (score 0):

try `$Label.css({color:'#8e8ef5'});`