# Selecting DOM Element in different ways brings different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I use this Code `$('#pills-testscript-tab')` then I get this result in Chrome dev tools:

```
k.fn.init [a#pills-testscript-tab.nav-link]`
```

This result is expandable and I can access all its functions. If I instead use `$('[data-toggle="pill"]')[1]` which is exactly the same DOM Element then I don't have access to all it's functions and the result in dev tools is:

```
<a class="nav-link" id="pills-testscript-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-testscript" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-testscript" aria-selected="false">Test Script</a>
```

This is not expandable.

I also tried to find a Function within the `$('[data-toggle="pill"]')[1]` object which provides me the same set of Functions like in the `$('#pills-testscript-tab')` object, but couldn't find any.

I don't understand why there is a difference. It might be that a Children Action `[1]` changes the behaviour in the result. If someone has any Idea let me know.

Thank's a lot!

Comment: To get a better understanding of JQuery objects and DOM Elements [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974603/7021694)

Answer (score 1):

> If I instead use `$('[data-toggle="pill"]')[1]` which is *exactly the same DOM Element*...

This is not the case. The first example, `$('#pills-testscript-tab')` returns a *jQuery object*.

The second example, `$('[data-toggle="pill"]')[1]`, is returning the second *Element object* found within a jQuery object because you're using an index accessor. This is why you see the difference in the console.

To return the second element in a collection as a jQuery object use `eq()`:

```
var $foo = $('[data-toggle="pill"]').eq(1);
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `eq()` as in my example

Comment: Crazy! Thank you so much! Nice I really was thinking about something like equaling. But I tought equaling stuff is not nice. But anyway it works for me.

Comment: I will mention you in the Software Project!