# cypress Timed out retrying: cy.its() errored because the property: clientHeight does not exist on your subject

Tags: cypress

The following:

```
cy.get( '@bar' ).
  its( 'clientHeight' ).
    should( 'eq', '300px' );
```

Fails with this CypressError:

```
Timed out retrying: cy.its() errored because the property: clientHeight does not exist on your subject.

cy.its() waited for the specified property clientHeight to exist, but it never did.
```

The browser supports [Element.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) because I use it in the code, and other assertions on the same alias correctly pass.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress command `cy.get()` yields a jquery object referencing a DOM element or a collection of DOM elements. You can find a good explanation of the difference at: [jQuery object and DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)

The way to get to the **clientHeight** property would be to accessed the DOM element from the yielded jquery object by using the [`get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method:

```
cy.get('@bar').should($bar => {
    expect($bar.get(0)).to.have.property('clientHeight', '300px');
});
```